# SonarQube does not start

Tags: java, sonarqube

I got a problem at SonarQube starting! In fact, it doesn't start and I don't get more informations only :

```
    --> Wrapper Started as Daemon 
Launching a JVM... 
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved. 

WrapperSimpleApp: Unable to locate the class org.sonar.application.App: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/application/App : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 

WrapperSimpleApp Usage: 
  java org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp {app_class} [app_arguments] 

Where: 
  app_class:      The fully qualified class name of the application to run. 
  app_arguments:  The arguments that would normally be passed to the 
                  application. 
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: "Unsupported major.minor version 51.0" <-- _that_ is your problem. You are trying to run SonarQube 5.x with Java 6 or less, and 5.X requires Java 7+

Comment: Right! It's ok. Thank you. It's just a jdbc connection issue now ;) Thank to you!

Answer (score 26):

We would need to set the right version of Java. In sonarqube-5.6, change the property in the file `sonarqube-5.6/conf/wrapper.conf`

> wrapper.java.command

to

> wrapper.java.command=/mypath/jdk1.8.0_73/bin/java

For Windows may need to edit from

```
wrapper.java.command=java
```

to

```
wrapper.java.command=mypath\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin\java
```

Comment: how do I find the java path? Turns out 1 uses where Java in windows. Usually its in program files.

Answer (score 8):

Install java JDK version 7u75 or higher,
Update your JAVA_HOME to point on the installed JDK directory.
Update your path to start with "%JAVA_HOME%/bin;"

Sonar require JDK 7u75 or higher : [View Sonar Requirements here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements)

Comment: The posted link returns 404

Comment: Updated link with the latest SonarQube requirements: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/requirements/requirements/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you were upgrading. Maybe you blindly replaced those two files from the old config folder to the new config folder (particularly mentioned in the upgrade documentation not to do so), because you will have classpath overridden in wrapper.conf, which shows same error.

Hope helps someone.